# geopandas projection problems

Tags: geopandas, proj

I'm handling `shp` files now and I encountered problems with the projections.
Let me give you my code below.

import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame
import os

```
Aelly = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\Hyun Mo\Downloads\조인 (1)\after_join.shp', encoding = 'utf-8') 
base_map = gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\Hyun Mo\Downloads\11000 (3)\TL_SCCO_SIG.shp', encoding = 'ANSI')
Aelly_to_crs = Aelly.to_crs(base_map.crs)
Aelly_to_crs.plot(ax=base_map.plot())
```

And here is my data construction

```
print(base_map.head())
```

[image: data construction]

```
print(Aelly.head())
```

[image: data construction]

When I executed `print(base_map.crs), print(Aelly_to_crs.crs)`, I got the results like below.

[image: results]

```
Aelly_to_crs.plot(ax=base_map.plot())
```

[image: data construction]

The above picture is the result of executing `Aelly.plot(ax=base_map.plot()`)
And you can see that the two pictures don't match each other.
How can I solve this problems??

-----------edit

My desired output is below picture.

[image]

Here are my data links:
http://blog.naver.com/khm2963/220929301892

below pictures are procedure for downloading my flie

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What is the expected output? What could be the issue? What have you tried? People probably won't download your files, so it's better if you give us a minimal example with data we can copy/paste

Comment: Oh~ Sorry~ I'm late. And I assume that people get my data from my link. But It doesn't work. 
I change my data link and add more information to my question. Sorry

Comment: Please consider sharing a few (or all) polygons on http://geojson.io/ or some similar service, so we don't have to download files!

Comment: Oh~ Sorry. But I don't know geojson.io. So Would you let me know your e-mail address?? I will forward my file to you. Thanks~~ Have a nice day~~

Comment: Did any of proposed solutions solve your problems? Then please mark that answer as selected for future visitors and in orderd to close the thread.

Answer (score 1):

From the data that you have printed it looks like everything is working as it should! The coordinates between the shapefiles are very different, but crs is the same, so the plot totally makes sense.

GeoPandas isn't able to tell you whether the data and number make sense in a real world. You gave it two shapefiles with well defined projection (EPSG: 32652) and with hardcoded coordinates and GeoPandas is happy with that.

If you know that in reality both shapefiles represent the same area, then you are the one that has to realize that datasource is somehow corrupt. I think that one of the shapefiles accidentally got a different crs definition as a metadata (imagine it as a wrong text encoding, for instance).

The easiest way to figure that out and correct it is by using ArcGIS or QGIS software, where you can play with different projections in order to figure out, what the correct projection was. Then you can save the shapefile with new projection metadata and the rest will work out of the box.